Can Zeckendorf's theorem be proven using generating functions?
First, I state Zeckendorf's theorem.
Zeckendorf's theorem states that every positive integer can be represented uniquely as the sum of one or more distinct Fibonacci numbers in such a way that the sum does not include any two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. More precisely, if $ N $ is any positive integer, there exist positive integers $ c_i \geq 2 $, with $ c_{i+1} > c_i + 1 $, such that
$$
N = \sum_{i=0}^k F_{c_i},
$$
where $ F_n $ is the $ n^{\text{th}} $ Fibonacci number. Such a sum is called the Zeckendorf representation of $ N $. The Fibonacci coding of $ N $ can be derived from its Zeckendorf representation.
Another theorem asserts a similar unique representation property: Every positive integer can be uniquely represented as the sum of distinct powers of 2.
This theorem has a beautiful proof using generating functions. The link I attach is:
Strong Induction Proof: Every Natural Number as Sum of Distinct Powers of 2
A natural question arises: Can generating functions be used to prove Zeckendorf's theorem?
(I have searched through many references but have mostly encountered proofs by induction.)

"Every positive integer can be uniquely represented as the sum of distinct powers of 2." To prove this , I would just use the binary representation of the given positive integer.

There certainly can't be a proof analogous to the binary proof; generating functions aren't very good at modeling the "no two consecutive Fibonacci numbers" condition.
